# Buildroot - Applying A Patch Failed

Tags: bluetooth, patch, embedded-linux, libtool, buildroot

I'm trying to build a custom kernel image for my [PhidgetSBC](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=19&product_id=1070) but I'm getting a failure during the build:

> bluez 4.96 Extracting
>
> bluez 4.96 Patching package/bluez
>
> for file in config.guess config.sub; do for i in $(find
>   /home/kerubu/buildroot_phidgetsbc/new/buildroot-phidgetsbc_1.0.4.20111028/output/build/bluez-4.96
>   -name $file); do cp package/gnuconfig/$file $i; done; done
>
> Patching libtool
>
> Applying buildroot-libtool.patch using plaintext:  patching file
>   ltmain.sh
>
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 273.
>
> Hunk #2 succeeded at 5412 (offset 3005 lines).
>
> Hunk #3 FAILED at 2551.
>
> Hunk #4 FAILED at 2895.
>
> Hunk #5 succeeded at 8058 with fuzz 1 (offset 2446 lines).
>
> Hunk #6 FAILED at 5937.
>
> 4 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file ltmain.sh.rej
>
> Patch failed!  Please fix buildroot-libtool.patch!
>
> make: ***
>   [/home/kerubu/buildroot_phidgetsbc/new/buildroot-phidgetsbc_1.0.4.20111028/output/build/bluez-4.96/.stamp_patched]
>   Error 1

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you use an old version of Buildroot in which we only had a patch against libtool 1.5, but your version of Bluez probably uses libtool 2.2. As a quick workaround, you can try to add the following line to the bluez .mk file :

```
BLUEZ_LIBTOOL_PATCH = NO
```

which will tell Buildroot to not apply the libtool patch.

However, the libtool handling has been improved since quite some time in Buildroot, so it's a bit of shame to not take advantage of the newer Buildroot releases.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Thomas. I'll try as you suggest when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the patch and 'ltmain.sh' are not in sync.  There's a couple ways this can happen. One is that 'autoreconf -f' has been invoked and the ltmain.sh that is copied down is not compatible with the patch. If you can at least remove the -f argument from autoreconf, it shouldn't rewrite it.

Comment: I'm not sure in which file I would need to remove the -f argument as to begin the build process I 'make' in the Buildroot root directory. It then automatically builds a kernel, downloads & builds my selected software packages etc so I'm not manually invoking the build on bluez. Any clues as to where this option would be?